# Oracle 10g install on Linux Red Hat 4.0

Tags: linux, redhat, users, groups

New to linux redhat and oracle 10g. Having problems creating an Oracle software user.

Input as /root

/user/sbin/useradd -g oinstall -G dba[,oper] oracle

Output

useradd: unknown group dba[ useradd: unknown group oper]

cat /etc/group showed the above groups were created.

Need help!!!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Oracle..

Answer (score 3):

/user/sbin/useradd -g oinstall -G dba[,oper] oracle

[] means optional input

use
/user/sbin/useradd -g oinstall -G dba oracle

This is a very good link with instrunctions:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/OracleDB10gInstallationOnRedHatAS4.php

Comment: +1 for the link to oracle base, the article is very good.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you['re seeing is that you need to create the group first using `groupadd`

Answer (score 0):

for when you have resolved the group issue - my standard resource for Oracle installs on Linux - [http://www.puschitz.com](http://www.puschitz.com/)

Specifically instructions for redhat [here](http://www.puschitz.com/InstallingOracle10g.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the oper group, which is why it's shown as [optional].

```
groupadd dba
groupadd oinstall
useradd -g oinstall -G dba oracle
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have an oinstall group created, if not:

```
    groupadd -g 501 oinstall
```

Once you have oinstall, try below command (make sure there is no space in comma separated values dba,oper):

```
    useradd -g oinstall -G dba,oper oracle
```

Comment: The missing groups were dba and oper, not oinstall.